# examining and modifying memory addresses in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I want to essentially do the following (which is probably dangerous and what not) just for the heck of it:

```
int main() {

    int x = 0x00ff00ff;

    printf("Value at addr x: %x\n",*x);


    return 0;
}
```

Basically take a look at the contents of a certain address in my machine. Maybe write to it. I'm guessing I'm not allowed to do the latter.

The error I get is `error: invalid type argument of 'unary *'`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not necessarily, @L7ColWinters, it depends on the implementation. It may be that, even in Linux or another protected-memory OS, someone has mapped real memory to that address. Or you may be running on a system that offers unfettered access to physical memory.

Comment: Because of virtual addressing, it's unlikely this is going to do anything too interesting, unless this happens to be an embedded environment or such.  If you really want to peek at the system memory, you need something like `/dev/mem` on Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a *pointer:*

```
int *x = (int*)0x00ff00ff;
```

And you're right, it's probably not a good idea, unless you *know* that `0x00ff00ff` is a valid address of some sort. It's not actually undefined behaviour since the standard says you can't dereference *illegal* addresses but then states that "illegal" includes things like:

- addresses of freed heap objects.
- NULL pointers.
- wrong alignment.

but doesn't explicitly list arbitrary pointer values, since that would make memory-mapped I/O in embedded systems problematic.

For example, you may control a UART (universal asynchronous receiver/transmitter, basically a serial port device) in an embedded system by reading or writing known memory-mapped I/O addresses:

```
#define UART_READ_READY  ((char*)0xff00)
#define UART_READ_CLEAR  ((char*)0xff01)
#define UART_DATA        ((char*)0xff02)

char getUartCharWithWait (unsigned int tries) {
    char retChar;
    unsigned int limit;

    // Keep looping until character available, at least for a while.

    limit = tries;
    while (*UART_READ_READY == 0)
        if (limit-- == 0)
            return '\0';

    // Get character, tell UART to clear it, then return it.

    retChar = *UART_DATA;
    *UART_CLEAR = 1;

    return retChar;
}
```

In this example, you have code like:

```
retChar = *UART_DATA;
```

which will read a byte (C `char`) from "memory" address `0xff02`, which will actually be from a device monitoring the address bus and intercepting specific addresses.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I tried just "int" for this example (which I did on codepad) was because I'm working on a small OS and I'm dealing with a data type called "paddr_t" (a physical address). With this data type I'm pretty sure I can do *paddr = 0x11223344 and follow generally the same pattern I tried in the OP.

Comment: Also great example for the memory-mapped I/O implementation with C.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the previously mentioned error because there is no way to *dereference* an `int`, making `x` a *pointer-to-int* will yield the "correct" result (ie. it will be able to compile).

```
int * x = (int*)0x00ff00ff;
```

---

<sup>*"It works, IT WORKS! Or er.. I mean, it compiles. **Now, what's a segfault?**"*</sup>